# How to use libusb.so library functions in C or JAVA coding after library is successfully loaded?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, usb, libusb, android-ndk-r5

I am trying to use libusb.so How can I make use of libusb library in my android project.

I have compiled libusb library for my android project using libusb source.Now I want to use the functions of newly generated library libusb.so in my code.
I've used following code..to just check the functions are loading or not..
What should I do to list device information in my app using libusb library.

code in jni directory..

## libTest.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_loadlibrary_MainActivity_libTask(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
if( libusb_init(NULL) )
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Library Loaded Successfuly!");
else
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Can not load library........");
}
```

## Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libusb-1.0

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libusb-1.0.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libTest.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

## libusb-1.0.so

and src contains this java file:

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.loadlibrary;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(libTask());
    setContentView(tv);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private native String libTask();
static{
    System.loadLibrary("usb-1.0");
    System.loadLibrary("libTest");
 }

}
```

but It shows error in ndk compilation:

**error: undefined reference to 'libusb_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make:  *[obj/local/armeabi/libTest.so] Error 1******

it shows that function is not defined in my code.
So how I will be able to get all the functions get working....

and atlast if I do

replace:
    if( libusb_init(NULL) )
with:
    if(1)

all files are generated but shows this error:

recipe for target `Loadlibrary.exe' failed  makefile    /Loadlibrary/Debug  line 31 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to`_WinMain@16'    Loadlibrary     line 39, external location: \usr\src\debug\cygwin-1.7.17-1\winsup\cygwin\lib\libcmain.c C/C++ Problem
make: *** [Loadlibrary6.exe] Error 1    Loadlibrary         C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 1):

First load your libraries and then use function inside it

```
      static{
      System.loadLibrary("usb-1.0");
      System.loadLibrary("libTest");
      }
      public final static native String libTask(String st); //libTask is returning a string also...
```

.so files are in "jni" folder so first check that after build are they created in "libs/armeabi" folder also??

Answer (score 1):

What I used to build with NDK and libusb support is the following: Add into you Android.mk

```
 LOCAL_LDLIBS :=-L/path/to/your/compiled/libusb.so -lusb
```

Give it a try. Hope this helps.